# Make a inherited function dynamic

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I have a Ruby project that has the following architecture:
[Project architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0AKm.png)

All of my child controllers (city1, city2) inherit from the parent controller at the project root. I have a method in the parent controller:

```
class Controller
  def get_directories
    Dir.chdir(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/")
    Dir.glob('*').select { |f| File.directory? f }
  end
end
```

My child controllers:

```
require_relative '../controller'

class City1Controller < Controller
end
```

and

```
require_relative '../controller'

class City2Controller < Controller
end
```

From my understanding, this method looks at the current Working Directory and returns an array of the folders that are inside that directory.

I expected the child controllers to inherit of this function in a way where the get_directories will be local to the child directory, but it's showing the folders in the parent directory.

That's what's happening:

```
controller.get_directories => city1 city2  
city1_controller.get_directories => city1 city2  
city2_controller.get_directories => city1 city2
```

That's what I want to happen:

```
controller.get_directories => city1 city2  
city1_controller.get_directories => monument1 monument2  
city2_controller.get_directories => monument3 monument4
```

If I repeat the exact same method in each child controller (thus overriding the parent definition), it works the way I want to. But isn't that what inheritance supposed to spare us?

Is the issue in the method itself, in how the inheritance works, or how I use it?

Comment: Post everything here directly. No part of your question should rely on an external site. And if you have code, post it here as text, not a picture.

Comment: Sorry, I had to troubleshoot which part of my text stackoverflow didn't like (gave error about code)

Comment: The issue is in how you use it. `__FILE__` is not a method and you shouldn't expect method-like behaviour from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sergio already pointed out: `__FILE__` is not a method. It is a reference to the current file's name, it returns a relative path to exactly that file in which it is located.

One option might be to pass `__FILE__` to the method like this:

```
class Controller
  def get_directories(file = __FILE__)
    Dir.chdir(File.dirname(file) + "/")
    Dir.glob('*').select { |f| File.directory? f }
  end
end
```

And the child controllers:

```
require_relative '../controller'

class City1Controller < Controller
  def get_directories
    super(__FILE__)
  end
end
```

And

```
require_relative '../controller'

class City2Controller < Controller
  def get_directories
    super(__FILE__)
  end
end
```